# Variable does not exist: email

Tags: apex, integration

RestRequest req = RestContext.request;

```
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response; 
    string jsonBody = req.requestBody.toString();
    Map<String, Object> obj=new Map<String, Object>();
    obj=(Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonBody);
    List<Object> ldobj=(List<Object>) obj.get('lead');  
      ldobj = [SELECT id, EMail, MobilePhone FROM Lead WHERE Email=:obj.email];
  for(Object lds: ldobj){
        map<string,Object>  leads= (Map<String,Object>) lds;
```

Hi all,
im newbie to salesforce, i queried an email which is integrated from website and getting error in my query as "Variable Does not Exist : email". Please help me with this and thanks in advance.!

Comment: You cannot use `obj.email` since `obj` is just a `Map<String, Object>`. You need to use `obj.get('email')` instead. Note that case for the key ('email') is important since Map keys are typically case sensitive.

Comment: NB: There's no need to assign your `obj` variable to a new Map then immediately throw that map away by reassigning from the results of `JSON.deserializeUntyped`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `obj.email` since `obj` is just a `Map<String, Object>`. You need to use `obj.get('email')` instead. Note that case for the key ('email') is important since Map keys are typically case sensitive.

NB: There's no need to assign your `obj` variable to a `new Map` then immediately throw that map away by reassigning from the results of `JSON.deserializeUntyped`.

```
RestResponse res = RestContext.response; 
String jsonBody = req.requestBody.toString();
Map<String, Object> obj = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonBody);

List<Lead> ldobj = [SELECT id, EMail, MobilePhone FROM Lead WHERE Email = :obj.get('email')];

for (Lead ld: ldobj) {
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Phil!